# Display the trash posts instead of published posts?

Tags: wordpress

I want to display the posts of post_status="trash" but not post_status="publish". In short, the posts in trash should get displayed on the site. For how long the trash posts would be available in trash? Any help would be appreciated.

**index.php**

```
<?php
// show all coupons and setup pagination
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'paged' => $paged
));
?>
<?php get_template_part('loop', 'coupon');  ?>
```

**loop-coupon.php**

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php appthemes_before_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class('item'); ?> id="post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">

        <div class="item-holder">

            <div class="item-frame">

      <div class="store-holder">
          <div class="store-image">
                        <a href="<?php echo appthemes_get_custom_taxonomy($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, 'slug'); ?>"><img height="89" width="110" src="<?php echo clpr_store_image($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, 'term_id', '110', null); ?>" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
          <div class="store-name">
                        <?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, ' ', ', ', ''); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php clpr_vote_box_badge($post->ID, $the_trans); ?>

                    <div class="item-panel">

          <?php clpr_coupon_code_box(); ?>

                        <div class="clear"></div>                               

                            <?php appthemes_before_post_title(); ?>

                            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'View the "%s" coupon page', 'appthemes' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php if (mb_strlen(get_the_title()) >= 87) echo mb_substr(get_the_title(), 0, 87).'...'; else the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                            <?php appthemes_after_post_title(); ?>

                            <?php appthemes_before_post_content(); ?>

                            <p class="desc"><?php echo mb_substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 200).'... ';?><a class="more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'View the %s coupon page', 'appthemes' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php _e('more &rsaquo;&rsaquo;', 'appthemes') ?></a></p>

                            <?php appthemes_after_post_content(); ?>    

                    </div> <!-- #item-panel -->


            </div> <!-- #item-frame -->


        </div>

    </div>

    <?php appthemes_after_post(); ?>
```

```
<?php appthemes_after_endwhile(); ?>
```

```
<?php appthemes_loop_else(); ?>
```

```
<h3><?php _e('Sorry, no coupons found', 'appthemes'); ?></h3>
```

`

Comment: umm... set them to published? they only should be set to trash if they are in fact trash.

Comment: Hi @PatrickEvans, I don't want the posts to be indexed because of some reasons. That's why I want to trash them after creating and want to display the trash posts.

Comment: So you want Published posts to be trash and Trashed posts to be publish? May I ask why?

Comment: Hi @brasofilo, I don't want the posts get indexed. That's why want to trash them and then display.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this *before your loop*

```
query_posts($query_string. '&post_status=trash');
```

Comment: Hi @Joe Buckle, I placed `query_posts($query_string. '&post_status=trash');` before loop. In result, no posts are displayed.

Comment: I've just tested this on a site I'm working on and it worked fine. Can you post your loop?

Comment: Hi @Joe Buckle, I changed the post with the code. Is this the code snippet you are asking?

Comment: Is there an appthemes_before_loop function?

Comment: Yes @Joe Buckle, it's there in loop-coupon.php
`<?php appthemes_before_loop(); ?>`

Comment: Try removing it but keeping query_posts($query_string. '&post_status=trash'); before the loop and let me know what happens

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35668/discussion-between-kishor-kumar-and-joe-buckle)